# Is there any specific resource tag in terraform to create a rule in eventbridge

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

e.g. We have a resource tag for event rule in cloudwatch as
`aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a combination of **[aws_cloudwatch_event_rule](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_rule.html)** to match the events you want to process with EventBridge and **[aws_cloudwatch_event_target](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_target.html)** to forward to another EventBridge Event Bus or to something like a Lambda which can directly process the events or to an SQS queue where the events can be processed by a consumer.

Here's a completely generic module for this purpose:

main.tf:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CREATE CLOUDWATCH RULES FOR EACH LOGICAL ROUTE TO MATCH EVENTS OF INTEREST
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "captures" {
  for_each = var.event_routes

  name        = replace(replace(each.key, "[^\\.\\-_A-Za-z0-9]+", "-"), "_", "-")
  description = each.value.description

  event_pattern = jsonencode({
    "detail-type" = each.value.event_names
  })
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONFIGURE EACH RULE TO FORWARD MATCHING EVENTS TO THE CORRESPONDING TARGET ARN
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "route" {
  for_each = var.event_routes

  target_id = each.key
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.captures[each.key].name
  arn       = each.value.target_arn
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "event_routes" {
  description = "A map from a meaningful operator shorthand to the target ARN and list of the event names that CloudWatch should forward to them."
  type = map(object({
    description = string
    event_names = list(string)
    target_arn  = string
  }))

  /*
  event_routes = {
    forward_to_kpi_tracker = {
      description = "Forward events to KPI tracker"
      event_names = [
        "UserSignedUp",
        "UserWatchedLessonVideo",
      ]
      target_arn = "arn:aws:events:ca-central-1:000000000000:event-bus/default"
    }
  }
  */
}
```

outputs.tf:

```
output "event_rule_name" {
  value = { for route_shorthand, route_details in var.event_routes :
    route_shorthand => aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.captures[route_shorthand].name
  }
}

output "event_rule_arn" {
  value = { for route_shorthand, route_details in var.event_routes :
    route_shorthand => aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.captures[route_shorthand].arn
  }
}
```

The target can be any of the following:

> - EC2 instances
> - SSM Run Command
> - SSM Automation
> - AWS Lambda functions
> - Data streams in Amazon Kinesis Data Streams
> - Data delivery streams in Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose
> - Amazon ECS tasks
> - AWS Step Functions state machines
> - AWS Batch jobs
> - AWS CodeBuild projects
> - Pipelines in AWS CodePipeline
> - Amazon Inspector assessment templates
> - Amazon SNS topics
> - Amazon SQS queues, including FIFO queues
> - The default event bus of another AWS account

From the [PutTargets API actions docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html).

Comment: Do you for sure that terraform supports "default event bus of another AWS account" as a target. because from their docs, it doesn't seem so, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#argument-reference

Comment: @vishal I am absolutely certain. We have four accounts configured to route matching events to the default event bus of other accounts and rely on it in production. The aws_cloudwatch_event_target resource's arn argument can be the ARN of a default event bus of another AWS account (this is what we do in production).  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#arn

Comment: If I want to set cloudwatch event rule to trigger a StepFunction state machine, do I need to setup any permission config after `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` and `aws_cloudwatch_event_target`?